# Iphone delegate memory leak problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need your help, i'm stacked on this project.

<del>When i run my applicaion into Instruments, →← marked line giving memoryleak. When the fist run everything is ok but second time →← marked line giving memory leak, i didn't understand why ? 

I tried a lot of things, i used NSAutoReleasePool as well but result same. 

Can someone help me pls ?


    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
 error = nil;
 → NSDictionary *results = [json objectWithString:response error:&error]; ←
 [json release]; 
 [response release];

 NSArray *responsedNetworks = [results objectForKey:@"networks"];   
 NSMutableArray *serverResponse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:responsedNetworks];   


Edit: 
I uploaded my example application to this address : [removed][1]  now, i'm sure that problem source isn't delegate, but i don't know where is the problem, I'm sure that Instruments shows wrong place for memory leak. I tried a lot of things can someone show me my mistake ?</del>

Thank you

**Edit 2:**
Guys Unfortunately, i tried Clang static analyser,as i expected it gave a couple of warning into the some line of codes, I fixed these warnings.

Now, Instruments giving leak error, but Clang says there is not error into project.

Finally, My problem wasn't gone.

Please download lastest example application and you can see with your eyes Here is the
[EXAMPLE Project source](http://hepsikolay.com/GivingMemoryLeak.zip).

How to see these leaks  : 
Open project and start to debug on the simulator (version doesn't matter). Start debug, you will see info button top of the corner on the opened first window. Press and open it, after that close info window and open it again, at this point you should see Instrument's leak messages. But Clang doesn't give anything i mean everything is allright on Clang side.

I'm really confused ? what should i do ?

Comment: If I know, i will fix them :)

Comment: Instruments will tell you what objects you're leaking. Note that the object you're leaking isn't (usually) the same as the object that leaks it.

Comment: Did you check my example project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instruments does not indicate the line that causes the leak. It indicates the line that allocated memory that later was leaked. Just from the code given (which is obviously not the entire code), I'd suspect that you're leaking serverResponse, which includes memory allocated in the line you've marked. Don't just look at the line that Instruments gives you. What class is leaking? That will give as much hint as the line.

Since you're starting to have trouble with memory management, a suggestion: when you release something, always set it to nil. This will save you a lot of headache and crashes later. In this case I'm talking about `json` and `response`:

```
[json release];
json = nil;
```

If you have Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2, run the Analyzer (Cmd-Shift-A). It will find most common memory problems automatically.

Comment: Hi Rob Thank you for your response. I'm currently using Leopard and X-Code 3.1.4 if snow leopard more usefull then this, i will upgrade my system asap. On the other hand i have already headache, i tried a lot of things. On the other hand, shall i trust Instruments ? probably i'm looking wrong place of mycode last few days.

Comment: By the way, i thought maybe problem coming from SBJSON (i know i know it stupid idea, even everybody using perfectly), then i changed json parser lines to TouchJson, i saw that result same, problem in my code, i'm sure that, but i don't know where. 

I uploaded my example application to this location : 
http://hepsikolay.com/MemoryLeakApp.zip

Could you download it please ?

Comment: And look at to Classes > Controllers > NetworkSelection.m line 33 you will see that line 

self.networkList = arrayResponse; 

I suppose problem coming from this line.

So, when changed this line to "self.networkList = nil;" It's working, it is not giving any memory leak into the Instruments.  

Where is the my mistake ? please save my mind.

Comment: Rob you are partially right, when i checked all of mycode, i found where is the problem in my project. I'm certainly sure about that, some times Instruments shows different problem source location. I thing every body be careful that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that is much easier to use than the Instruments. The tool is the Clang Static Analyzer. [The website describes](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) how to install and use the tool set. It is so easy to use and very efficient. I use it all the time.

The commands are:

```
xcodebuild clean
scan-build -k -V xcodebuild
```

It is really easy to use as the results come up in the web browser!  It will catch leaks that Instruments does not catch.  This is the tool Apple has integrated in Snow Leopard... it is available to you in Leopard too.  Check out [the website for directions](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)..

Hope this helps!